# In Go, how to write a multi-line statement?

Tags: go

In python, we use backslash to indicate that the current statement continues to next line

for example,

```
a = b + c + s \
    + x + y
```

or simply,

```
a = b + c + s +
    x + y
```

Is it possible to do that in Go language? Thanks

Comment: No, we don't. We use brackets. Also, we put operators whose operands strech across lines on the end of the first line, not of the start of the second. See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Nitpick: That's not a valid python expression - you're missing an operator.

Comment: lol apparently, i am so good with python either. Thanks for pointing that out. I will fix that.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Sure it is, just put an operator at the end, for example:

```
a = b + c + s +
    x + y
```

Also note that it's not possible to break the line before the operator. The following code is **invalid**:

```
a = b + c + s
    + x + y
```

The rule is described [here](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#semicolons) and in the [specification](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Semicolons).

Comment: But will `gofmt -w` keep your lines split?

Comment: Care to make the *invalid* bold?

Comment: @Elazar: Yes, as expected, `gofmt` does keep the line split.

Comment: Also works for function chaining over several lines... nice!

Answer (score 18):

Interestingly, the the Go language specification itself requires semicolons at the end of each statement, but the lexer will insert implicit semicolons at the end of lines that *look like* statements immediately before compilation.

Therefore, to prevent the unwanted semicolon at the end of an unfinished line, all you need to do is ensure that the line doesn't end with something that could make it *look like* a complete statement.

In other words, avoid ending an incomplete line in a variable, constant, function, keyword, or postfix operator (e.g. `++`).

What does that leave? Well, a few things come to mind -- an infix operator (e.g. `=` or `+`), a comma, or an opening paren or brace or bracket, for example.

Comment: Coincidentally, this is the same policy that Javascript has regarding semicolons, and has been known to cause unintended behavior, even in seemingly benign cases.  Nothing is stopping you from putting them there yourself, if you'd rather be safe.

Comment: It's not exactly the same as JavaScript, unfortunately. JavaScript won't insert a semicolon in the middle of a parenthesized expression. Go will, which makes wrapping things nicely much harder.